# Animate text inside flexbox using css

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am new to the web development, and recently I came across [this](http://www.danielspatzek.com/Home) website and wanted to give it a go.I
I used flexbox to style the layout. The problem is I can't figure out how to animate the text on hover like in the website, and also the vertical text is not exactly in the center. And also let me know is flexbox even a right choice to make this kind of layout. Thanks for any help.

Here my css code:

```css
    <style>
        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #homeBox {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            height: 100vh;
        }

        .navBarRow {
            height: 100px;
            background-color: white;
            vertical-align: middle;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .navBarCol {
            width: 100px;
            background-color: white;
            vertical-align: middle;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #abt, #contact, #newsBlog, #projects {
            font-family: "Comic Sans MS", monospace;
            font-size: 10px;
        }

        #abt:hover {
            font-size: 22px;
        }

        #projects:hover {
            font-size: 22px;
        }

        #newsBlog:hover {
            font-size: 22px;
        }

        #contact:hover {
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        .middleBox {
            flex: auto;
            display: flex;
        }

        #about {
            flex: auto;
            background-color: white;
        }
    </style>

Here my html code:
```

```html
<body>
<div id="homeBox">
    <div class="navBarRow">
        <div id="newsBlog">
            <h2>NEWSBLOG</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="middleBox">
        <div class="navBarCol">
            <div id="abt">
                <h2>A</h2>
                <h2>B</h2>
                <h2>O</h2>
                <h2>U</h2>
                <h2>T</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="about"><h1 align="center">SOMETHING HERE</h1></div>
        <div class="navBarCol">
            <div id="contact">
                <h2>C</h2>
                <h2>O</h2>
                <h2>N</h2>
                <h2>T</h2>
                <h2>A</h2>
                <h2>C</h2>
                <h2>T</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navBarRow">
        <div id="projects">
            <h2>PROJECTS</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve the hover effect, I animated the `margin-top` and `letter-spacing`

I removed/changed/added properties to make use of Flexbox's features (see comments in CSS).

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
#homeBox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
.navBarRow {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;                                              /*  added  */
  align-items: center;                                        /*  added  */
  justify-content: center;                                    /*  added  */
}
.navBarCol {
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;                                              /*  added  */
  align-items: center;                                        /*  added  */
  justify-content: center;                                    /*  added  */
}
#abt, #contact, #newsBlog, #projects {
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", monospace;
  font-size: 10px;
}
#abt h2, #contact h2 {                                        /*  added rule  */
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
  transition: margin-top .5s;
}
#abt:hover h2 + h2, #contact:hover h2 + h2 {                  /*  added rule  */
  margin-top: 15px;
}
#newsBlog h2, #projects h2 {                                  /*  added rule  */
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  transition: letter-spacing .5s;
}
#projects:hover h2, #newsBlog:hover h2 {                      /*  added rule  */
  letter-spacing: 15px;
}

.middleBox {
  flex-grow: 1;                                               /*  changed  */
  display: flex;
}
#about {
  flex-grow: 1;                                               /*  changed  */
}
```

```html
<div id="homeBox">
  <div class="navBarRow">
    <div id="newsBlog">
      <h2>NEWSBLOG</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="middleBox">
    <div class="navBarCol">
      <div id="abt">
        <h2>A</h2>
        <h2>B</h2>
        <h2>O</h2>
        <h2>U</h2>
        <h2>T</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="about">
      <h1 align="center">SOMETHING HERE</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="navBarCol">
      <div id="contact">
        <h2>C</h2>
        <h2>O</h2>
        <h2>N</h2>
        <h2>T</h2>
        <h2>A</h2>
        <h2>C</h2>
        <h2>T</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navBarRow">
    <div id="projects">
      <h2>PROJECTS</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Here is an update, with the text rotated as in the linked site, animating only the `letter-spacing`

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
#homeBox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
.navBarRow {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;                                              /*  added  */
  align-items: center;                                        /*  added  */
  justify-content: center;                                    /*  added  */
}
.navBarCol {
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;                                              /*  added  */
  align-items: center;                                        /*  added  */
  justify-content: center;                                    /*  added  */
}
#abt, #contact, #newsBlog, #projects {
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", monospace;
  font-size: 10px;
}
#abt h2, #contact h2 {                                        /*  added rule  */
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}
#contact h2 {                                                 /*  added rule  */
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
#abt h2, #contact h2,
#newsBlog h2, #projects h2 {
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  transition: letter-spacing .5s;
}
#abt:hover h2, #contact:hover h2,                             /*  added rule  */
#projects:hover h2, #newsBlog:hover h2 {
  letter-spacing: 20px;
}

.middleBox {
  flex-grow: 1;                                               /*  changed  */
  display: flex;
}
#about {
  flex-grow: 1;                                               /*  changed  */
}


/*  styles for this demo only, so hover looks good in small snippet window  */
@media (max-height: 300px) {
  body { overflow: hidden; }
  .navBarRow { height: 30px; }
  #abt:hover h2, #contact:hover h2, #projects:hover h2, #newsBlog:hover h2 {
    letter-spacing: 12px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="homeBox">
  <div class="navBarRow">
    <div id="newsBlog">
      <h2>NEWSBLOG</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="middleBox">
    <div class="navBarCol">
      <div id="abt">
        <h2>ABOUT</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="about">
      <h1 align="center">SOMETHING HERE</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="navBarCol">
      <div id="contact">
        <h2>CONTACT</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navBarRow">
    <div id="projects">
      <h2>PROJECTS</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good answer, as always

Comment: @vals Thanks...trying to :)

Comment: Nice pure CSS solution +1

Comment: @LGSon you sir deserve a medal. Thank you so much.